# Open a linkless button in google chrome

Tags: excel, vba, url, browser

I'm trying to write a macro that can download chart data from tradingview.com. The problem is that the "Export" button that downloads the CSV file does not have a link (See screenshot). I have the code figured out and it works perfectly (screeenshot below), but I'm just not sure what URL to put.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Buttons typically do not "open a link" - They submit data using form based HTML - you cannot just copy/paste a URL to make that work.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in VBA? It's critical I automate the chart export because there are over 30 charts that need to be downloaded each time this runs.

Comment: Only if that website allows you to do it some other way. Keep in mind that stock market websites typically do not want you automating things, so they do everything they can to prevent you from doing it.